# Swift and Python: get a RunLoop that can run in threading

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, loops, ctypes

I am trying to write a Swift standalone library to monitor a NSUserDefaults value and callback a function in Python. To do so, I need an event loop in the Swift code that allows the Observer code to run and, when needed, call the callback function.

Swift provides `RunLoop` for this purpose, which works fine also when interfaced with `ctypes` **from the main Python thread**. However, the moment I wrap my calls in `threading` to avoid blocking the main Python code (the whole point of callbacks), `RunLoop` also returns immediately and becomes useless.

The following contains a minimal example to reproduce this behavior. No functional code is included, just the loop and its invocations from Python.

- runLoop.swift

```swift
import Foundation

@_silgen_name("run")
public func run() -> Void {
    // Some convenience code to allow interrupting with Ctrl-C from Python
    let signalCallback: sig_t = { signal in
        exit(signal)
    }
    signal(SIGINT, signalCallback)

    RunLoop.current.run()
}
```

Build this by running  `swiftc -emit-library -o ./loop runLoop.swift`

- pyrun.py

```py
import ctypes
import threading

loop = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./loop')
loop.run.argtypes = None
loop.run.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

#loop.run() #this works

t = threading.Thread(target=loop.run)
t.start()
t.join()
```

Run this via `python3 pyrun.py`.

Running the code as it is results in immediate return. On the other hand, when uncommenting the `loop.run()`, the Swift loop correctly runs indefinitely.

Funny thing, if `multiprocessing` is used instead of threading, the Swift loop continues to work, so this must be something very specific to how `threading` is creating the threads. Just FYI, the same happens with Objective-C and `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Python, but is behaviour of runloops themselves. I get the same behaviour when using an ObjC program that uses `pthread_start` to create a thread that runs the runloop.

The `-[NSRunLoop run]` method will return immediately when there are no timers or sources attached to the runloop (see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop/1412430-run))

There's probably an input source attached to the main thread, although I don't know how to check for this.

Comment: Thanks, I started to suspect that, but I was not able to find an alternative to the standard runloop that a) runs indefinitely and b) does not block calls made by `UserDefaults.standard.addObserver` (the point of this exercise).

Comment: Where does `addObserver` come from? I don't see it in the docs of `UserDefaults`

Comment: It's part of KVOs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412787-addobserver

This is how the call in init looks like:
`UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: key, options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], context: Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>.none)`

Comment: In the end I posted the same question on the Apple Developers Forum, with way more Swift-related details https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710135?login=true&page=1&r_s_legacy=true#720551022